# SDK Manager some Licenses Have not been Accepted

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I'm getting the following error while trying to run **`./gradlew build`**

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following Android SDK packages as some licences have not been accepted.
     build-tools;29.0.2 Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2
     platforms;android-29 Android SDK Platform 29
  To build this project, accept the SDK license agreements and install the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, see http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

But when I run **`./sdkmanager --licenses`** I get:

```
Warning: File /var/jenkins_home/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So kinda stupid mistake that I did, I was using the [xmartlabs/jenkins-android](https://hub.docker.com/r/xmartlabs/jenkins-android) image which according to its `Dockerfile` set `ANDROID_HOME` to `/opt/android-sdk-linux`. Which was also mentioned in the error, I didn't notice it. Anyways I ended up creating an android sdk in a separate directory, where the license were accepted and so kept getting the unaccepted license agreements' error.